# Encode Arc<RwLock<serde_json>> to PostgreSQL jsonb

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx, rwlock

*Obligatory disclaimer: I'm definitely no Rust/SQL expert, but I'm still learning. I'd appreciate any help in this process.*

I am trying to encode a struct containing a field of type `Arc<RwLock<json>>` into the `jsonb` PostgreSQL type using the sqlx crate. My code takes the general form:

```
...
use std::sync::Arc;
use parking_lot::RwLock;
use serde_json::value::Value as json;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ArcJson {
    pub data: Arc<RwLock<json>>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    ...
    pub my_data: ArcJson,
}
... 
// this is an associated function (self is sqlx::postgres::PgPool)
pub async fn add_my_struct_instance_to_db(self, my_new_data: MyStruct) -> Result<MyStruct, sqlx::Error> {
     match sqlx::query("INSERT INTO postgres_table (..., postgres_jsonb_data) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING ..., postgres_jsonb_data")
        .bind(my_new_data.my_data)
        .map(|row: PgRow| MyStruct{
            ...
            my_data: ArcJson {data: Arc::new(RwLock::new(row.get("data")))},
        })
        .fetch_one(&self.connection)
        .await{
            Ok(data) => Ok(data),
            Err(e) => Err(e)
        }
}
```

The error I'm getting is that the trait bound 'ArcJson Encode<_, Postgres>' is not satisfied.

I've tried to derive sqlx::Type for ArcJson to no avail. What is the simplest way to basically say "to convert all you have to do is read the locks and clone the internal json"? (I know cloning here isn't the most efficient thing, but I'd like to avoid going down [this sort of rabbit hole](https://github.com/graphql-rust/juniper/issues/969) if I can avoid it for now).

Lifetime annotations scare me, but they're required to manually implement [encode](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.6.2/sqlx/trait.Encode.html). Can anyone advise on how I should proceed? I'm not sure if my brain is just too small or I'm over-complicating things.

*PS: I tried to simplify the code as much as possible to best convey the gist of the issue, please let me know if it is unclear or confusing*

Comment: Why not just do the locking before the query, then send the inner `json` value?

Comment: "What is the simplest way to basically say "to convert all you have to do is read the locks and clone the internal json"?" doing exactly that. Neither Arc nor locks are really magic in rust (though Arc does have some compiler support in that [it's one of the MSRV arbitrary self types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55786), nothing out there will go "do the magic thing on the magic thing".

Comment: "Lifetime annotations scare me, but they're required to manually implement encode." Looking at [existing implementations](https://docs.rs/sqlx-core/0.6.2/src/sqlx_core/postgres/types/interval.rs.html#196) it seems rather straightforward and nothing to be afraid of. You can probably delegate the actual encoding to `sqlx::types::Json`, so all you need to do in your `encode` is acquire the lock.

Comment: @Masklinn Yeah, you're right, thanks for the reassurance. I think I had just been spoiled by mostly being able to derive traits with procedural macros thus far. I'm going to give that a try, and update with my solution in a bit, then I'll close the question.